# ReactJs functional component add function to an eventListener and then invoke it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-functional-component

Is it possible to create an event listener in a functional component and then invoke it from chrome console?

For example:

```
const Component = () => {
   const [hook,setHook] = useState();

   const handlerFunction = (arg) => {
      console.log(arg);
   }

   // how to add an event listener?
   return <div>Hello world<div>
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: @programmer Because I have an external clientside application which can run CeF and I can execute JS from the clientside to CeF. I wish to execute this handlerFunction so that the component would rerender based on passed props. My initial idea was to add an event listener to this function and trigger it. Maybe you have other suggestions?

Comment: You can make the function global, but I would not recommend that, props is the way to go, you can use a `useEffect`

Comment: Can you provide an example on how to invoke it using javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to add a global variable:

```
const Component = () => {
    const [ value, setValue ] = useState();

    window.MY_GLOBAL_CONTAINER = (arg) => {
        setValue(arg);
        console.log(arg);
    };

   return <div>Hello world, { value }</div>
}
```

which you can access with:

```
MY_GLOBAL_CONTAINER('test')
```

Probably better to use a [*ref*](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html):

```
const Component = () => {
    const [ value, setValue ] = useState();
    const ref = useRef(null);

    useEffect(()=>{
        ref.current.handlerFunction = (arg) => {
            setValue(arg);
            console.log(arg);
        };
    },[])

    return <div ref={ ref } id="containerElementInsideTheDom">Hello world, { value }</div>
}
```

which you can access with:

```
document.getElementById('containerElementInsideTheDom').handlerFunction('test')
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for!!!! Thank you very much. I am using typescript so the first example worked with (window as any).handlerFunction = (arg) => {...}

Comment: The second one, however could'nt make it to work but no problem as the first example was the one I was looking for!!!